# insufficient privilege on changing opportunity owner despite sharing rule

Tags: security, sharing

Hi i have our OWD setup for Opportunity object = Private then we have this sharing rule:

Owner in Role: Sales Manager shared with owner in Role:Sales Rep (Read/Write)

now our Sales Manager created an opportunity and when Sales Rep open the record and click on 'Change' on the Owner field, 'Insufficient Privileges' prompt.

any rules i missed out?

Thanks.

Comment: Is transfer records option enabled in your profiles ?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, transfer records will allow all the user that profile to transfer any record no?

Comment: Yes, that's correct